# How to read Parquet files under a directory using PySpark?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I have searched online and the solutions provided online didn't resolve my issue. I am trying to read parquet files under a directory which are hierarchical. I am getting the following error.

> 'Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually.;'

My directory structure looks like:
dbfs:/mnt/sales/region/country/2020/08/04

There will be multiple sub-directories for months under the year folder and subsequent sub-directories under month for days.

I only want to read them at the sales level which should give me for all the regions and I've tried both of the below codes but neither of them worked. Please help me with this.

```
spark.read.parquet("dbfs:/mnt/sales/*")
```

or

```
spark.read.parquet("dbfs:/mnt/sales/")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you try this option?

```
df = spark.read.option("header","true").option("recursiveFileLookup","true").parquet("/path/to/root/")
```

Comment: Thanks @Lamanus! This seems to have worked. I am also looking to filter based on a date range but looks like these have timezones inside them which is returning zero records. What am I missing here?
df = spark.read.option("header","true").option("recursiveFileLookup","true").parquet("/path/to/root/").filter("StartDate>= '2020-08-04T00:00:00.000'& "EndDate < '2020-08-04T12:00:00.000'")

Comment: It is another question and you'd better post it again with your sample data.

Comment: Sure, I posted the question here based on your suggestion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63581549/filter-between-datetime-ranges-with-timezone-in-pyspark-for-parquet-files

Comment: Thanks @Lamanus also a question, does `spark.read.parquet(<s3-path-to-parquet-files>)` only looks for files ending in `.parquet`? I will have empty objects in my s3 path which aren't in the parquet format.Just wanted to confirm my understanding.

Answer (score 2):

```
path = '/mnt/container_name/root_dir/folder_name'
df = spark.read.format('parquet').options(header=True,inferSchema=True).load(path)
```