# Filter between datetime ranges with timezone in PySpark for parquet files

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

Based on the suggestion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63580115/how-to-read-parquet-files-under-a-directory-using-pyspark/63580182?noredirect=1#comment112431476_63580182), I would like to know how do I filter the datetime ranges with timezone using PySpark.

Here is how my data looks like:

> ABC, 2020-06-22T19:17:16.428+0000
>
> DEF, 2020-06-22T19:17:16.435+0000
>
> JKL, 2020-06-22T19:17:16.468+0000
>
> MNO, 2020-06-22T19:17:16.480+0000
>
> XYZ, 2020-06-22T19:17:16.495+0000

I would only like to extract those records that has milliseconds between 400-450 in this case.

Tried this but didn't work:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
df = df.select(func.to_date(df.UpdatedOn).alias("time"))
sf = df.filter(df.time > '2020-06-22T19:17:16.400').filter(df.time < '2020-06-22T19:17:16.451')
```

Comment: Can you give the schema of df? `df.printSchema()`

Comment: root
 |-- time: date (nullable = true)

Answer (score 1):

When you use `to_date` it will truncate the hours, so you have to use `to_timestamp` and compare it.

```
df.withColumn('date', to_timestamp('date')) \
  .filter("date between to_timestamp('2020-06-22T19:17:16.400') and to_timestamp('2020-06-22T19:17:16.451')") \
  .show(10, False)

+---+-----------------------+
|id |date                   |
+---+-----------------------+
|ABC|2020-06-22 19:17:16.428|
|DEF|2020-06-22 19:17:16.435|
+---+-----------------------+
```

Comment: I replaced date column in your code with "UpdatedOn" which is my column in OP but getting an error: cannot resolve '`UpdatedOn`' given input columns

Comment: Test to use your code with to_timestamp and modify your filter.

Comment: How did you read your data and make a dataframe? If it is possible, please add some more code that the earlier part of what you posted.

Comment: I read the data from a Source database and written it as a parquet file. Now, for my delta loads in the DWH, I would only like to pull the records that changed from yesterday. As mentioned in my other post for hierarchy (Table/year/month/day), I would like to pass a date and read the parquet file that only matches the records after the date.